# Why doesn't Pandas round when dtype is float16?

Tags: python, pandas

Why does Pandas not round DataFrames when the dypes are `np.float16`?

`pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10) for x in range(0, 10)).astype(np.float16).round(2)`

Or

`np.round(pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10) for x in range(0, 10)).astype(np.float16), 2)`

Or

`pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10) for x in range(0, 10)).astype(np.float16).round({0:2, 1:2})`

This must have come up before but I can't find it anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

It *is* rounding. Up to the limits of float16 precision, the results are exactly what you asked for. However, the limits of float16 precision are significantly lower than the 6 significant figures Pandas attempts to print by default, so you see some of the representation imprecision that is usually hidden when printing floating-point numbers.

Comment: I don't understand, when I change the `dtype` to `float.64` (i.e. the default) I see the output as I would like, which is just 2 d.p., if what you're saying is true then shouldn't this be the same for both types of float?

Comment: @0_fazistinho_: Pandas is stripping trailing zeros in that version of the test.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I 100% follow, but you know a lot more about this than I do, what do you think the solution to this is then? I use float16 to reduce the size of the database because it's quite a lot of data but I don't want to see so many decimal places when I view my DataFrame

Comment: I don't think there's any option to customize the default display precision just for float16. Anything you do will probably either be cumbersome or have undesirable side effects for how other dtypes are displayed.